# Why My approved Edit review required another review

Tags: support, editing

I noticed this thing couple of times, when somebody edit a post(question or reply), it move to the suggested edit reviews and when i picked that one and approved it. After that i noticed that even I Approve it but still required another approval on top of me?

If i click on edit button, it mentioned (1) and also next windows tells me that you already approved it but required another approval.

So question is why 2nd approval required if I Approved it, is it mistrust or some rules which i dont read?

Who is the 2nd Approver Moderator or who?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ### Who can suggest an edit?
>
> - Registered users without the edit privilege (2000 rep) can suggest
>     edits to any post or tag wiki.
> - Registered users who have the edit
>     privilege but are not trusted users (between 2000 and 20000 rep) can
>     suggest edits to tag wikis.
> - Anonymous users can suggest edits to any
>     post more than 10 minutes old. These edits are attributed to the
>     Community user upon approval. Where do suggested edits go?
>
> Suggested edits are held in a peer review queue of a fixed size. If
>   the queue fills up, no more edit suggestions will be allowed until the
>   queue has some empty space.
>
> ### Who can vote on a suggested edit?
>
> - The owner of a post may cast a binding vote to accept or reject any
>     modification of their post.
> - All users with the edit privilege may vote
>     on suggested edits to posts.
> - Users with 5000 rep may vote on suggested
>     edits to tag wikis.
> - Two (or three on SO) accept or reject votes are
>     required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply
>     the edit to the post or discard it. It used to be a single vote (two
>     on SO)

[Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

Mainly what applies here is the last paragraph, as long as you are not a "trusted user" (20 000 reps, or moderator) there will always be two reviews made on suggested edits.

The fact that you sometimes see you changes immediately and sometimes doesn't, is probably due to the fact that sometimes you are the first reviewer (where you have to wait for another user to approve as well) and sometimes you are the second reviewer (where some other user has already given an OK)